# Highcharts - Stacked Bar Column - Total Value of Stacked Bar not Correct with Negative and Positive Values

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying out Highcharts and I have a situation where I have negative values and positive values within one bucket on the x-axis.  The total for the stacked values is not accurately represented on the y-axis and the y-axis stackLabel.

For instance, in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zamapps/mn2fx5yt/), the Oranges have -30, 20 and 40.  The total is showing 60; not 30.

Here's a snippet of the Highcharts object showing the data:

```
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [50, -30, 40, 70, 20]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [20, 20, 30, -20, 10]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [30, 40, 40, -20, 50]
        }]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the highcharts stackLabel sum values from negative and positive values separately. Take look at your exampel and you will notice that you have stacklabel -30 and 60, separaterly calculated.

Comment: I think that's the problem I am having.  I want the values in the bucket to be added together not separately if they are negative or positive.

Comment: @shawnzizzo: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using the [yAxis.stackLabels.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.stackLabels.formatter) property as below:

```
yAxis: {
           stackLabels: {
               enabled: true,
               align: 'center',
                         formatter: function() {
                   var sum = 0;
                   var series = this.axis.series;

                   for (var i in series) {
                       if (series[i].visible && series[i].options.stacking == 'normal') 
                           sum += series[i].yData[this.x];
                   }
                   if(this.total > 0 ) {
                       return Highcharts.numberFormat(sum,1); 
                   } else {
                       return '';    
                   }
               }
           }
       }
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34640701/1132522).